# Are there metrics for Redhawk performance

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a dual channel radio where I have two `RX_DIGITIZER_CHANNELIZERs` and two `DDCS`. My waveform allocates both channels. The waveform just takes the data from each channel and outputs it to two `DataConverters`. I am using the snapshot function to capture data. When I start to collect data at higher rates some of the packets get dropped. Is there a way to measure how long a call such as pushPacket takes? If I used the logging function, it would produce too much output to measure how long it takes.

Comment: With regard to this, I can set my DDCs sample rate to 2.5Msps and when I monitor the ports from my DataConverter I see about 8.5MBytes/sec. However, if I take a snapshot from the DataConverter dataShort_out port it appears that it cannot keep up and I drop some samples. If I run about 1Msps I have no problem saving the data. Is there a way to optimize the saving of the data to a file?

Answer (score 0):

@michael_sw can you plot the data coming from the device in the IDE instead of saving to disk?

How are you monitoring the packet drops?

Do you need to go through the data converter?   If you have to it is possible to set a blocking flag in SRI in the downstream REDHAWK device (see chapter 15 in manual) to cause back pressure and block until data converter is done consuming the previous data.  This only helps if the data converter is dropping packets.

In the IDE there is a port monitoring mode where you can actually tell when data is being dropped (right click on port and select port monitoring) by a component.

Another option in the data converter you could modify the code to watch the getPacket call for the inputQueueFlushed to be true.

Comment: This answer gives some good advice, but consider placing the questions as comments to the original question, if these are aspects that the OP should clarify.  Maybe you will need to edit your answer after the answers are there ...

Answer (score 0):

I commonly use timestamping - make a call to one of the system clock functions and either log the time or print the time to the console.  If you do this in the function that calls pushPacket and again in the pushPacket handler then you simply take the difference.  If this produces too much data, you can simply use a counter and log it only every 1000 calls, etc.  Or collect the data for a period of time in an array and log/print them after the component is shut down.  Calls to the system clock does not effect performance much compared to CORBA calls.